# ReCaptcha in web-to-lead form using PHP recaptcha.lib in Site.com salesforce

Tags: validation, authentication, site.com, web2lead

I have created a web-to-lead form and I am using the generated HTML in my site.com. I am using reCaptcha in my form.

**HTML Web-to-Lead form**

```
<form action="/recaptcha_verify.php" method="post"  name="emailForm" id="test" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" >
<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D40000000IUAQ">
<input type=hidden id="From_Link" maxlength="255" name="From_Link" value="<?=$cameFrom ?>"  /> <!-- came from link  //-->
<input type=hidden id="Campaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" value="701400000005waD"> <!-- Google Ad Words //-->
<input type=hidden id="recordType" name="recordType" value="0124000000014Ed"> <!-- Google Ad Words //-->
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.thankyoupage.com/merci-beaucoup">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td >First Name: <br />
      <input  style="width:200px;" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >Last Name: <br />
      <input  style="width:200px;" id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >Email:<br />
        <input  style="width:200px;" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td >Company:<br />
      <input  style="width:200px;" id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >Country: <br />
        <input  style="width:200px;" id="country" maxlength="40" name="country" size="20" type="text" />
       </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td >Region: <br />
<select  id="Region" name="Region" title="Region"><option value="North America">North America</option>
<option value="South America">South America</option>
<option value="EMEA">EMEA</option>
<option value="APAC">APAC</option>
</select></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>     
      <td align="left" >
      <span class="style1 style2">Verify Code:<br />

        <br />
        <!-- Captcha//-->
        <?

echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);

         ?> 
        <!-- Captcha //--></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**recaptcha_verify.php**

```
<?
ob_start();
session_start();

include_once('recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');

         //Recaptcha Settings
       $publickey = "xxxx"; // you got this from the signup page
       $privatekey = "xxxx";

       extract($_POST);
       if ($submit){  //if its sumbitted

        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        $ok = 1;

            if (!$resp->is_valid) { //if captcha is  invalid
              $ok = 0;  
            }

            if ($ok){   
               //Put here the data for sf leads storing
            }
            else {
              // Message here that the captcha was invalid 
            }   
       } 

?>
```

The problem is  when I submit my form, site.com do not run PHP code instead it downloads the php file on client side. Do I need to setup my own PHP server to process this request?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I almost downvoted this, then realized I was entirely wrong. and this is a totally a legit question. Well played.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce.com doesn't run PHP. It runs Visualforce and Apex Code. As such, you can't just drop reCaptcha or any other PHP open source solution into place for a successful captcha service. You will probably need your own server to host the PHP so you can validate the codes. Try this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=apex+code+captcha) for some ideas.

Top hits include:

1. [Calling reCaptcha from a remote server](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Adding_CAPTCHA_to_Force.com_Sites).
2. [Rolling your own captcha](http://www.tehnrd.com/simple-visualforce-captcha/).

Comment: But Site.com doesnt' support Apex.

Answer (score 0):

In doing some research today on CAPTCHA, I discovered [Adding CAPTCHA to Force.com Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Adding_CAPTCHA_to_Force.com_Sites) in the Technical Library on how to implement reCAPTCHA on Force.com sites when submitting forms included within VisualForce pages.

The link includes a sample VisualForce Page plus code for an Apex Controller to handle the reCAPTCHA verification, reset and other functionality.